# SQLAlchemy circular dependency on delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have built some models like below in `SQLAlchemy 1.0.11`

```
class HasID(object):
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column('id', Integer, Sequence('test_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    ...


class TestParent(HasID, Model)
    __tablename__ = 'tests'
    discriminator = Column(String(50))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': discriminator}
    ...


class FooTest(TestParent, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('footests.id'))
    children = relationship('FooTest',
                            foreign_keys='FooTest.id',
                            lazy='joined',
                            join_depth=2,
                            cascade='save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan')
    ...


class BarTest(TestParent, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bartests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'bartests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Now, when I try to delete an instance of BarTest using below:

```
mytest = TestParent.query.get(30) # is an instance of BarTest
db_session.delete(mytest)
db_session.commit()
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1559)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/Downloads/pycharm-5.0.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2407, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/xxx/Downloads/pycharm-5.0.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1798, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/scratches/sql_scratcher.py", line 38, in <module>
    db_session.commit()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 150, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 813, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 392, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 372, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2027, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2145, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2109, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 365, in execute
    postsort_actions):
  File "/home/xxx/xxx/data_app/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/topological.py", line 36, in sort_as_subsets
    _gen_edges(edges)
sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. (DeleteState(<FooTest at 0x7f9b74a2e590>), DeleteState(<FooTest at 0x7f9b74a2e510>))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am confused as to how to set up `FooTest`. I am trying to delete an instance of `BarTest` by interacting with `TestParent`, although getting an error referring to `FooTest`

Comment: Can you post what data do you have in all three tables? It looks like you have `foo1` with `parent_id=foo2` and `foo2` with `parent_id=foo1` and you are trying to delete one of them. But you said that you are trying to delete `bar` and not `foo` and I don't see how it can raise such an error. Side note: you probably don't need to inherit `FooTest` and `BarTest` from `Model`, because you inherit from the `TestParent` which already inherits from the `Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, provided by the king of the SQLAlchemy mailing list, is that I need to change

```
class FooTest(TestParent, Model):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('footests.id'))
    children = relationship('FooTest',
                            foreign_keys='FooTest.id',
                            lazy='joined',
                            join_depth=2,
                            cascade='save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan')
```

To

```
class FooTest(TestParent):
    __tablename__ = 'footests'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'footests'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tests.id'), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('footests.id'))
    children = relationship('FooTest',
                            foreign_keys='FooTest.parent_id', # CHANGE HERE!!
                            lazy='joined',
                            join_depth=2,
                            cascade='save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan')
```

I had specified an incorrect foreign key on the relationship between `FooTest` parents and `FooTest` children.

I also removed `Model` from the `FooTest` inheritance (per Boris's comment), although this was not causing any errors